# Kendo DataSource - Read from Remote Data Service

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to create a Kendo dataSource bound to a remote data service, but whenever I try to read the remote data source using accountsListDs.read() or accountsListDs.fetch() method, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/umHYMjm8

I double checked my code, re-read Kendo documentation, but don't know what to make of it. I can use $.ajax and get a response, and then the response to be DataSource, but I'd like to use Kendo's CRUD functionality.

Can any Kendo UI expert help me?

```
var accountsListDs = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://localhost:8085/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.office.web.services.AccountsService",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                op: "list"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What happens if you open in your browser `http://localhost:8085/cabinet/wicket/bookmarkable/com.office.web.services.AccountsService?op=list`?

Comment: @OnaBai I see the JSON response.

Comment: Your error message makes it look like you are trying to pull data from Everlive (Telerik BackendServices), but your sample code here does not. Maybe something is missing?

Comment: @CodingWithSpike That's the issue. I'm unable to figure out something as simple as this. Exactly the reason why I hate Kendo so much. As a paying customer, I still can't post this question on their forums.

BTW, I'm a great fan of your blog. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Kendo DataSource doesn't work when kendo.data.everlive.js is reference in your document. I commented out the reference to that js file, and things worked. Weird.

Comment: That is interesting. I think kendo.data.everlive modifies the base DataSource to work with Telerik Backend Services (formerly called Everlive) but I thought you had to specify to your datasource that it was supposed to use everlive. Maybe that isn't the case any more and just including the file at all overrides the base functionality. Thanks for posting your solution!